# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have installed *react-navigation* in my **React Native project**. Its a starter project doesn't have any codes. But while running project I am facing error like this.

Here is my Navigation code

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './screens/Home';
import WeatherDetail from './screens/WeatherDetail';


const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  WeatherDetail: {
  screen: WeatherDetail
 } 
});

export default Navigation;
```

And here is the App.js codes

```
 import Navigator from './Router';


 export default class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Navigator />
       </View>
     );
    }
  }
```

If I remove the navigator component from the App.js and replace it with a **Text** the application runs without any error.

Comment: This all looks correct, can you show the code for the `Home` component?

Comment: You need to link it with `react-native link` I guess.

Comment: I was facing the same problem in iOS. In that case you can try to add RNGesture library manually. https://tuntunir.blogspot.com/2019/02/null-is-not-object-evaluating.html?m=1

Answer (score 96, accepted):

1. remove node_modules and package-lock.json
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install --save react-navigation`
4. `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
5. `react-native link`

Comment: If the error persists even after all the steps, it is because of backslashes, then change this line of code to this:                                                          
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')

Comment: following these steps as well as uninstalling the app then rebuilding worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using react-link to link your dependencies:

1. 0pen your ios Podfile and delete all yout linked dependencies: pod 'xxxxxxx', :path => '../node_modules/xxxxx
2. Close Xcode
3. In your /ios folder run "pod update"
4. In your project source run "react-native link"
5. Open Xcode and Clean Build Folder from Xcode Menu -> Product
6. Run your application from Xcode
7. Link manually the dependency "react-native-gesture-handler" into your Xcode Project following steps in documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios
8. Now run your application from Xcode, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

From the official doc:

> If you're on React Native >= 0.60, you need to disable autolinking for react-native-gesture-handler first. To disable autolinking for it, create a react-native.config.js file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-gesture-handler': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

If your are using React 0.60, just omit this official doc. Follow following steps:

1. `rm react-native.config.js` if exist
2. `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`
3. `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
4. `react-native run-ios`

Comment: Is it also true in expo project? Because it is not written anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error on ios from RN v0.60

The following worked for me:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: Excellent. Simplest (and probably most correct) solution. This answer should be moved up!

Answer (score 3):

First, remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.
After installing the `react-navigation` package in your React Native project. You should install react-native-gesture-handler. If you’re using Expo you don’t need to do anything here, it’s included in the SDK. Otherwise:

`npm install react-native-gesture-handler`

And finally, link gesture dependency as:

`react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

This answer based on the [React Navigation document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 2):

maybe someone come here because same problem as me.

i got this error because i'm using react-navigation version 3.x, in that version `stackNavigator` is change to `createStackNavigator` and should use `createAppContainer(createStackNavigator)`

im fix it just like [mr.amiri said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370597/7084334) but im not delete my node_module im just follow step 3 - 5

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not allowed to comment, I am posting it here. This is the answer by @Amiri Houssem but I am adding one more thing:

1. `remove node_modules and package-lock.json`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install --save react-navigation`
4. `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
5. `react-native link`

If there is an error even after these 5 steps, check android/settings.gradle and change that line to this:

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```

Comment: I don't think you need step 1 and 2 for this, but always good to be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering because none of the above answers were relevant to me.

I got this error because VSCode automatically inserted `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'` as a dependency in my file when I added a `<TouchableOpacity>` element.

Give the last files you edited a once-over just in case there's an import statement you don't expect!

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the CLI to solve the issue

```
cd iOS
pod install

cd ..
react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled the app from the device and run the android project - react-native run-android and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

you can check your version of react-native 
if React Native 0.59 and lower you can

```
 react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

and check your `@react-navigation` version in

> https://reactnavigation.org/versions

Answer (score 0):

may be its late.
Temporary solution downgrade the version of react navigation:
1- unlink and uninstall react-navigation and the handler 
2- add  **"react-navigation": "^2.18.2"**  to package.json
3- remove node_modules folder
4- npm i
5- react-native link

Answer (score 0):

if you have done the above, it hasn't run yet, try this
if you use Windows

```
cd android 

.\gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

and try running it

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `react-native-gesture-handler` is present in `node_modules` folder, we need to add it to path or install it again. Then link with native code.

1) `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`

```
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.15
info All dependencies
└─ react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.15
```

2) `react-native link`

```
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-gesture-handler ios dependency 
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-gesture-handler has been
 successfully linked 
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-gesture-handler android dependency 
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-gesture-handler has
 been successfully linked
```

3) `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a configuration with Podfile in ios. Follow this steps:

- Comment this line `pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'` in `<react-native-project>/ios/Podfile`.
- Open `<react-native-project>.xcworkspace` Add `RNGestureHandler.xcodeproj` in Libraries (Right click over library folder and select "Add files to ") from `node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios`.
- Add `libRNGestureHandler.a` in (Build Phases) -> (Link Binary With Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me as well.
1) `npm install react-navigation`
2) `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`
3) `npm intstall`
4) `react-native link`

uninstall the app

5) `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands in command prompt (Run as Administrator)

```
 npm install react-navigation
 npm install react-native-gesture-handler
 npm intstall
 react-native link
```

Re-Install the application will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this and none of the above answers worked for me. Here's what I had to do:

- Delete your `ios` folder entirely.
- Delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`.
- Restart your computer.
- Run `react-native eject` to re-create your native code folders.
- Run `npm install`
- Run `react-native link`
- Run `npm run start -- --reset--cache`
- Now run `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

see your native react version, if version 0.60 then you must migrate to androidX using a jetifier, follow the steps in this link
https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier

successful for me :)

Comment: Please keep in mind, that linked content might be moved or deleted, then your answer might get useless. Better is to mention the link but include the most useful content of this linked content into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on React Native >= 0.60:

You should see the following entry in your `ios/Podfile`:

```
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
```

If this line is not there, first run:

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

`ios/Podfile` should now contain a new entry.

Now run this command from iOS directory `/ios/`:

```
pod install
```

Run your iOS project again either directly using `XCode` or `react-native run-ios`