# React Native - undefined is not an object(evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.state')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I get this error and it's driving me insane, I cannot even start a simple application on React Native. I am using the most basic example, with a fresh project and still throws this error.
I use **react-navigation v3xx**
Someone please help because I am losing my mind, thank you.
Here is the code I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json


class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Home",
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')} title="All about me" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class AboutMeMe extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "All Me",
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} title="<< Back" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppScreens = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  About: AboutMeMe
})

const App = createAppContainer(AppScreens);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});


export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861437/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rngesturehandlermodule-state?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hellow

As react navigation now depends on gesture so you must install an additional library to go after you have installed the react-navigation library

Run this command inside your project from your terminal

`npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`

Then run this one

`react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

These instructions are well explained here

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation

for new react navigation version

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks