# React Native Error: Undefined is not an object RNGestureHandlerModule

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I know this is a duplicate of many other questions, but I have followed the setup tutorial at:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation

I've tried a bunch of stack overflow answers and most of them look something like this:

```
remove node_modules and package-lock.json
npm install
npm install --save react-navigation
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
react-native link
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370597/8512499

The interesting thing is that the projects works fine if I start it up from inside Xcode, but if I run `react-native run-ios` it fails.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is the error I'm getting:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code where the import statement lives?

Comment: if you mean the imports on my navigator, its:

import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

Comment: Have you tried linking react-native-gesturehandler manually?

Answer (score 0):

**I still faced the issue**

On closer look and reading other documentation i found at times pods are the real issue.

**This I how It got it working**

delete the app from the simulator

```
 run on terminal -> react-native link
```

Goto IOS folder

```
 run on terminal -> pod install
```