# Navigating to new page

Tags: react-native

I just started working with React Native and I wanted to use React Navigator to go to a new Screen. I followed the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) but I keep running into a problem.

I have an App Navigator file below

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LandingPage from './src/components/LandingPages/LandingPage';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: LandingPage },
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

And my App.js file is

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
   <AppNavigator/>

   );
  }
}
```

However, I get the error below.

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')

<unknown>
GestureHandler.js:55:37
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
Swipeable.js:11
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
index.js:1
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
StackViewLayout.js:19
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
StackView.js:4
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
createStackNavigator.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
createStackNavigator
index.js:9:18
createStackNavigator
react-navigation.js:107:45
<unknown>
AppNavigator.js:4:21
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
App.js:13
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
<unknown>
index.js:7
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
require.js:199:45
global code
<unknown file>:0
```

I have also tried

1. remove node_modules and package-lock.json
2. npm install
3. npm install --save react-navigation
4. npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
5. react-native link

But I still get the same error. Anyone has any ideas ?

**EDIT**

It is happening in ios

**EDIT**

Package.json

```
    {
      "name": "AppName",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
      "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
,     "test": "jest"
      },
     "dependencies": {
     "react": "16.6.3",
     "react-native": "0.58.4",
     "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
     "react-navigation": "^3.2.1"
   },
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
   },
   "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
 }
```

}

Comment: Where does the error happen ? is it `ios` or `android` ?

Comment: if it's in android then you probably forgot to make changes to `MainActivity.java` file

Comment: It is happening in ios

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861437/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rngesturehandlermodule-state)

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it didnt work. I will try again

Comment: I tried that again and it did not work. The same error

Comment: Can you show your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

If it's in android then make sure to add those changes to `MainActivity.java` after you link the package check [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation)

```
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
+ import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
.
.
.
+  @Override
+  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
+    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
+      @Override
+      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
+       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
+      }
+    };
+  }
```

That's usually the issue.

Comment: I added that to the android part but it is happening in ios

Comment: Do you have a pod file ?

Comment: I just created one

Comment: try to remove node_modules `pod install` again and it should work, that happens all the time when you have a pod file, I keep deleting node_modules and start all over again till it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Andriod u have to make changes to MainActivity.java 
For ios 
Add this to your podfile:

```
pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios'
```

You're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I was not using the StackNavigator correctly and I did not have the GestureHandler installed and lined correctly.

I created a new project, copied my old files into it and changed the Navigator class as such and it began to work fine.

```
  import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
  import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage/LandingPage';
  import Login from './components/Login/Login';

 const stack = createStackNavigator({
     Landing: {
         screen: LandingPage,
          navigationOptions:{
             header: null,
         },
     },
     Login: {
         screen: Login,
     },

 });

 const App = createAppContainer(stack); <----- Key emphasis

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this problem is not rebuilding the app. 
follow these steps

1. close the `metro builder` terminal window
2. run `react-native run-ios` again (or run-android in case you are facing the issue in android).

If this doesn't fixed your issue

1. try deleting the app from device.
2. run `react-native run-ios` again.

If you are on android and this issue still haven't fixed check if your `MainActivity.java` matches with the one provided in their installation instructions.