# null is not an object (evaluating 'rngesturehandlermodule.direction')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a login system with react-native, after downloading the `"react-native-gesture-handler" dependencies: "^ 1.1.0"` and `"react-navigation": "^ 3.5.1"` began to appear the following message error:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'rngesturehandlermodule.direction')

I tried to delete the project and reface it, delete and reinstall the node_modules folder and reinstall the dependencies, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I then installed `react-navigation` & `react-native-gesture-handler` step by step as follows:

**Steps :**

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install --save react-navigation`
4. `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
5. `react-native link`

You can find the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370597/3239250)

Answer (score 9):

`cd` into the `ios` subdirectory of your project and run `pod install`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Stop the `metro bundler` with `Ctrl+C` from terminal.
2. Run again metro bundler: `npx react-native start`
3. Run again the build command `npx react-native run-android`

Building process maybe take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this on Android.

All I did is:

1. cd android
2. gradlew clean
3. closed metro bundler
4. react-native run-android

solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and just **restarted the Metro Bundler and iOS emulator**. It seemed to work when I restarted them.

Answer (score 1):

For android,

1--> cd android/

2--> ./gradlew clean

3--> cd ../

4--> Run your project now

I don't know is this an exact answer?
But it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please first run this command in terminal :

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

Second :

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

Third :

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Forth :

```
npm start
```

Finally, this is work.

Comment: after link liked you said, i got another error: requireNativeComponent:"RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager

Comment: Now you do this works => 1:npm nuinstall react-native-safe-area-context --save , 2: npm install react-native-safe-area-context --save , 3: react-native link react-native-safe-area-context , 4: npm start.   :))

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same error on ios from react-native v0.59.9.
The following solution works for me.

1. npm i react-native-gesture-handler
2. react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
3. cd ios && pod install && cd ..
4. react-native run-ios

> tip: react-native support autolinking from [v0.60.0](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0600)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I solved it using npm instead of yarn.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-run your application every time you install a new dependency via npm.
close app then run npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

All I did was :

1. restart metro server: ctrl+c then yarn start
2. react-native run-android `// basically reinstalling the project after installing react-navigation`

Answer (score 0):

I have same error but it solve by create file separate file for Navigation File with name "MainNavigator.js"

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; 
import HomeScreen from '../screen/Home';
import DetailsScreen from '../screen/Details';

    const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Details: DetailsScreen,
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
    );


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default AppContainer;
```

And Use it in App.js file with following code

```
import React from 'react';
import RootNavigator from './js/navigation/MainNavigator';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RootNavigator />
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android try this solution :
go to : /android/settings.gradle there was string:
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')

tro to change it with :
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
source : #494 (comment)

Answer (score 0):

`npx pod-install` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are on react-native version 0.59.10 try these steps for ios:**

1. Change in package.json "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.1.1"
2. npx react-native link --platforms ios
3. Open Xcode and on top where it shows the library > iphone or whatever device your building for, change library to point to RNGestureHandler and run that separately and ensure that builds fine. Then switch back to your project and run/build that.
4. May not be related but I also had to manually build RN screens.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

As easy as that.