# Android 'react-native-gesture-handler' error

Tags: react-native

When I follow the instruction by the react-navigation website : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html.

react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

and then change the MainActivity.java like it asks.

Then run react-native run-android, and error pop up :
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:

react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
my react-native version :
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.0

However, when I follow the instruction, to unlink the library
use : react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler

The app successfully built, but now it pops up another error in the app :
null is not an object (evaluating 'rngesturehandlermodule.direction')

I tried a lot of solution in a lot of websites, like
[undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861437/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rngesturehandlermodule-state)

non of them is working for me

Comment: Did you run pod install . After react native version 0.60 you do not have to run react-native link  but still you have to run pod-install command after you install the library using npm/yarn . [AutoLinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) .Please run pod install and then check again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861437/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rngesturehandlermodule-state)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is to do with the new autolinking feature in `RN 0.60`.

**For iOS**

To fix for now just add the following podspec for RNGesureHandler to ios/Podfile

```
pod 'RNGestureHandler', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec'
```

Then in the ios directory run `pod install` to install it.

**For Android**

Path: `android/app/src/main/java/com/projectname/MainApplication.java`

```
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
....
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        // Add additional packages you require here
        // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            ....
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage()
        );
    }
```

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what went wrong, but very possibly because of the react-native-cli that upgraded from below 0.60.0 to above it.

**BEFORE 0.60.0** when running react-native run-android, the command will run a metro packager, along with building the android app, and then run the app that connect to the metro packager.

That's why in the past, we only run one command **"react-native run-android"** to run the project.

But **AFTER 0.60.0** when running react-native run-android, the command will only build the android-app, and run the app to connect to the metro packager.

I saw a command prompt blinked once, might also be how the command start the metro packager went wrong and the packager just closed itself somehow.

**Also** as for the problem with `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler` I believe it is the new feature of react-native 0.60.0 to autolink library, so manual linking of library is not necessary anymore. As a lot of the library provider might need to start providing auto-linking features, or might face the same error, not just react-native-gesture-handler.

**Temporary Solution** until someone fix the react-native-cli to run the metro packager again:
Open 2 command prompt instead of 1. And run the command below on each of the command prompt:

1. `react-native start`
2. `react-native run-android`

You might want to run the first command first and wait for it to be ready before running the 2nd.

Otherwise, you app might turn out to be blank.

Source : I tried it myself by creating new project and running the command as mentioned by the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, first uninstall react-native-gesture-handler.

Then delete IOS and Android folder.

Then run below command.

1.react-native upgrade --legacy true // to recover ios and android folder.

2.npm install react-native-gesture-handler

3.react-native link

4.react-native run-android

5.react-native run-ios

Also update your MainActivity.java file , follow official website:

https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

Did you run react-native run-android or react-native run-ios ?